# Null pointer exception when retrieving textView in onCreate using shared preference

Tags: nullpointerexception, textview, sharedpreferences, oncreate, data-retrieval

Here is my code in onCreate method

```
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("key", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
     String tValue = sp.getString("textvalue","");
     coins.setText(tValue);
```

This is where iam saving text value

```
    count++;
    coins.setText(String.valueOf(count));
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("key", 0);
     SharedPreferences.Editor sedt = sp.edit();
     sedt.putString("textvalue", coins.getText().toString());
     sedt.commit();
```

Comment: can you post your logcat output ?

Comment: it just says NULLPointerException

if i comment this line in oncreate then app runs normally but without the comment line the app crashes                                               coins.setText(tValue);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem will be resolved by this line..Try it

```
TextView coins = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourcoinsid);

  coins.setText(""+tValue);
```

**Reason**

The instance variable coins was null , so we find it using findViewById and then it will work.

Comment: Try it now, your coins reference is null

Comment: How foolish I am :3
It worked Thankyou Sir you are great!